# How can I get the google analytics website css, js

Tags: analytics

How can I get the analytics website css, js

I would like to put the tables, charts, and grap shown on the analytics website into the page I develop website . I am importing it through API, but I need a design that shows it. How can I get css html javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Google Analytics Embedded API**, it is a JavaScript library that allows you to embed a dashboard in your system with the same design of Google Analytics:

[image]

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started